# Current Sql Date in Spring StoredProcedure Causes ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

Tags: java, sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm compiling a current system date in my Java/Spring as following:

```
Calendar calobj = Calendar.getInstance();
java.sql.Date currentSysDate = new java.sql.Date(calobj.getTime().getTime());
```

When this date is inspected, it has the following format:

```
2014-04-01
```

I'm passing this value to my extended `StoredProcedure` class's `execute()` method in a `Map` (updating via an *Oracle* PL/SQL):

```
public Object execute(java.sql.Date currentSysDate) {

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("current_date", currentSysDate);

    return execute(params);
}
```

The PL/SQL:

```
{call update_curr_date (
current_date => :current_date
)}

PROCEDURE update_curr_date(current_date  IN DATE) AS
BEGIN

       INSERT INTO plogger (plogger_id, use_case_name, wrapper_name, logged_updates) 
       VALUES (plogger_id_seq.nextval,
           'Date use case',
           'UPDATE_CURR_DATE',
           'current_date = "' || current_date || '"');

END update_curr_date;
```

Which results in the following exception being thrown during my unit testing:

```
ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
ORA-06512: at line 4
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Added both the query string used in *Spring* and *PL/SQL* interface. I do not think these additional information would be relevant as the wrapper executes just fine when run in SQL Developer passing the same exact date format ('2014-04-01')

Comment: @Malvon - it is relevant because your procedure is expecting the parameter to be a date. Both calls (from Spring and SQL Developer) are passing a string so both are doing an implicit conversion to `date`; and since one works and the other doesn't, the two sessions have different `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` settings. You have a `sql.Date` but it seems it's being translated to a string when it's bound; you haven't shown the binding step though.

Comment: @AlexPoole Can you elaborate more on the *binding* step. I am not quite following. Thank you.

Comment: @Malvon - you're doing a `call` with bind variable `:current_date`; can you include the code where you set that value (bind) to the `params` value `current_date` - I assume that's a `setString()` call. (Unless Spring handles that for you under the hood; another technology I don't use!)

Comment: @AlexPoole I see. The value is being passed directly to `execute()` and Spring's `StoredProcedure` class takes care of details (`CallableStatement`) internally.

Comment: OK, looks like the error is coming from the procedure, not the call. Can you add the procedure, or at least the start of it? I'd guess you're doing something like an unneccessary `to_date(current_date, '<format>')` in there (on line 4), which would also fail for some NLS_DATE_FORMAT values.

Comment: @AlexPoole I updated the post with a complete stored procedure code. I am not doing anything special with the date other than inserting into another table. The strange part is, even when I set its value to `null` in the `Map` object, it still throws the same exception. I am baffled! Running the stored proc in SQL Developer with `NULL` works, but not when I set the date value to what my JDBC passes, i.e. `2014-04-01`. I have tried other formats, but the issue persists for some reason.

Comment: An attempt to take out the entire `INSERT` statement still produces the same ORA fault. If I pass a hard coded value, `new java.sql.Date(2342342323L)`, it also fails. I took out the date parameter entirely in PL/SQL, and now the invocation goes through without an issue. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original stored procedure I was using had multiple required parameters, including `current_date`. I was receiving the same exception which prompted me to trim down all the parameters and only use the `DATE` parameter at no avail.

Finally I gave up and put back all the parameters back in the PL/SQL stored procedure and declared parameters in the `StoredProcedure` class. What the issue was, and I can't figure why, is the *order* in which the parameters were being declared, i.e.:

```
PROCEDURE update_curr_date(
  h_id    IN NUMBER,
  h_type   IN VARCHAR2,
  h_pnum IN VARCHAR2,
  h_curr_date    IN DATE,
  mode         IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'INSERT');
```

And had it declared in `StoredProcedure`:

```
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("h_id", OracleTypes.NUMBER));
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("h_curr_date", OracleTypes.DATE));
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("h_type", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("h_pnum", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
```

And the query string:

```
{call update_curr_date (
h_id => :h_id,
h_type => :h_type,
h_curr_date => :h_curr_date,
h_pnum => :h_pnum
```

**Note**: `mode` is dynamically appended to the end of SQL query string along side its corresponding declaration since it's an optional parameter, but that's beside the point.

When I moved `h_curr_date`'s declaration to the end of `declareParameter()`, it worked:

```
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("h_id", OracleTypes.NUMBER));
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("h_type", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("h_pnum", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("h_curr_date", OracleTypes.DATE));
```

Given that I am using a named parameter to do my declaration and binding the variables, it is odd that *Spring* (or perhaps Oracle implementation of JDBC, but I suspect the former since mapping is done in the *Spring* code) doesn't work in this case when parameters are declared out of order (I've had some weird outcome with `OUT` parameters too).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your code completely ? Do you use correct type for binding as Alex Poole asked ? This example should work to you:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE update_curr_date(current_date  IN DATE)
is
begin
       insert into t values(current_date);
end;
/

class SP extends StoredProcedure{ 
        private static final String SPROC_NAME = "update_curr_date"; 
        public SP( DataSource datasource ){ 
               super( datasource, SPROC_NAME ); 
               declareParameter( new SqlParameter( "current_date", OracleTypes.DATE ) ); 
               compile(); 
        } 
        public Object execute(java.sql.Date p) { 
               Map<String,Object> results = super.execute(p); 
               return null;
        }
} 

...
    public void updateDate() {
        Calendar calobj = Calendar.getInstance();
        java.sql.Date currentSysDate = new java.sql.Date(calobj.getTime().getTime());        
        SP psp = new SP(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
        psp.execute(currentSysDate);
    }
...
```

Check what your parameter uses DATE type binding.

Comment: My code is identical to yours with the right binding type of `OracleTypes.DATE`.

Comment: Even when I pass `null`, I get the same error. Why? And even `new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())` repeats the same exception.